# How can I install and use Hyprland in Ubuntu?

Tags: wayland

Lately, I have been trying to look for the way to install and use Wayland compositor [Hyprland](https://hyprland.org/) in Ubuntu 22.10.

How can I do that?

Comment: From o [here](https://wiki.hyprland.org/Getting-Started/Installation/#distros): _...since Hyprland is extremely bleeding-edge, distros like Pop!_OS, Ubuntu, etc. might have major issues running Hyprland_

Answer (score 2):

Start by cloning the git repository and then start building.
Once it complains about a source not being available, `apt-get install` the dev package for it.

If you don't find it in the apt repository, you have to download it manually from the web and build it yourself.

Do that for about 6 hours, and then you'll get Hyprland to work.
Just make sure that you don't really update Ubuntu, because it will likely break Hyprland.

Source: Myself, I did it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the show but I'm trying to install it as well.

Per the [documentation](https://wiki.hyprland.org/Getting-Started/Installation/) you have to install the dev dependencies, then compile/install:

```
sudo apt-get install -y meson wget build-essential ninja-build cmake-extras cmake gettext gettext-base fontconfig libfontconfig-dev libffi-dev libxml2-dev libdrm-dev libxkbcommon-x11-dev libxkbregistry-dev libxkbcommon-dev libpixman-1-dev libudev-dev libseat-dev seatd libxcb-dri3-dev libvulkan-dev libvulkan-volk-dev  vulkan-validationlayers-dev libvkfft-dev libgulkan-dev libegl-dev libgles2 libegl1-mesa-dev glslang-tools libinput-bin libinput-dev libxcb-composite0-dev libavutil-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libxcb-ewmh2 libxcb-ewmh-dev libxcb-present-dev libxcb-icccm4-dev libxcb-render-util0-dev libxcb-res0-dev libxcb-xinput-dev xdg-desktop-portal-wlr
```

The instructions are of Ubuntu 23.04, it looks like you might need to install gcc-12 if you are on a version.

Now get the source code and compile it:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/hyprwm/Hyprland
cd Hyprland
sudo make install
```

This should work for the nominal case.